# Check if image URL is cached or not on cross-platform. React-Native

Tags: react-native, image, caching, react-native-image

In the react-native component, I am trying to use default Image while offline. But online comes back, I should use image loaded from URL recently.
But if this URL is cached already, react-native Image don't update image with new one that loaded recently. Because react-native Image component is using div's background-image, and it's using first loaded image.

I am trying to check if image URL is cached already. and this solution should works on multi-platforms include mobile, web, ios.. etc